# python mysql custom re-connect class does not hold server connection open

Tags: python, mysql, database, exception, connection

I have a custom class written in python to re-establish a mysql connection, if the current connection is dead.  The only problem is, the current one always seems to be dead and is always entering into the except block of my try-except.

```
class DB:
    conn = None
    def connect( self ):
            try:
               self.conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxxxx", "Systems")
            except ( AttributeError, Mysqldb.OperationalError ), e:
               raise e

    def query( self, sql, params ):
            try:
               cursor = self.conn.cursor()
               cursor.execute( sql, ( params ) )
            except ( AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError ), e:
               print 'exception generated during sql connection: ', e
               self.connect()
               cursor = self.conn.cursor()
               cursor.execute( sql, ( params ) )
            cursor.close()
            return cursor

    def close( self ):
            try:
               if self.conn:
                  self.conn.close()
                  print '...Closed Database Connection: ' + self.conn
               else:
                  print '...No Database Connection to Close.'
            except ( AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError ), e:
               raise e

db = DB()
db.query( sql, myParams )
```

The problem is two-fold.  1) When I call `db.close()` I get `...No Database Connection` output.  2) Each time I execut `db.query( sql, myParams )` it enters the except clause and outputs `exception generated during sql connection:`

It seems like my db connection is closing itself after each query call.  But I don't know why this would be happening.  Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first time you make a call to `db.query`, self.conn is equal to
  None. So indeed, you will always get a `exception generated during sql connection`
  message the first time you call `db.query`. However, subsequent calls
  to `db.query` will not produce that message.

  If you add

  ```
  def __init__(self):
      self.connect()
  ```

  then `self.conn` will be initialzed when you create `db = DB()`. Then
  you will not get the error message. Or, if you only want to create a connect on-demand, then just take out the error message.
- You can remove `conn = None` from the DB class. The code will still work, in basically the same way, by raising an AttributeError when `self.conn` is not set.
- Note also that, if your `sql` is a SELECT statement, you should not
  call `cursor.close()` in `DB.query`, since a subsequent call to
  `cursor.fetchall()` will no longer work.

---

Here is some example code to show that, with the changes mentioned above, the `exception generated during sql connection` message is only printed once, and the `db.close()` prints
`...Closed Database Connection:` as it should.

If your code is behaving otherwise, please modify the code below to demonstrate the behavior.

```
import MySQLdb
import config

class DB:
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost",
                                        config.USER, config.PASS, config.MYDB)
        except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError), e:
            raise e

    def query(self, sql, params = ()):
        try:
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql, params)
        except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError) as e:
            print 'exception generated during sql connection: ', e
            self.connect()
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql, params)
        return cursor

    def close(self):
        try:
            if self.conn:
                self.conn.close()
                print '...Closed Database Connection: ' + str(self.conn)
            else:
                print '...No Database Connection to Close.'
        except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError) as e:
            raise e

db = DB()
sql = '''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo'''
db.query(sql)

sql = '''CREATE TABLE foo (bar INT(11))'''
db.query(sql)

db.close()

# exception generated during sql connection:  DB instance has no attribute 'conn'
# ...Closed Database Connection: <_mysql.connection closed at 8769f8c>
```

---

config.py:

```
USER = 'myusername'
PASS = 'mypasswd'
HOST = 'localhost'
MYDB = 'dbname'
```

Comment: I agree that my first call to db.query() will generate the exception but my issue is that each and every subsequent call to db.query is generating the error also.

Comment: I've added some code to demonstrate what I mean. I'm not seeing an exception with every call to `db.query`, just on the first call (as expected). Please modify the code to demonstrate the error.

Comment: sorry for the ignorance but could you explain (or provide doc reference) for the config method you are using to pass username, password, and database to the connect command?

Comment: No problem; I use `config.py` to define private variables. It's just a file with a few variables defined (see above). You can import it into other python scripts and access the variables with `config.whatever`.

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing where you have done anything substantially different from my code. I see you removed the `conn = None` and the `cursor.close()` and I understand the rationale behind both.  But I don't see how your recommendation will change how my code executes in order to make it work.  You started talking about adding an `__init__` method inside my class but then did not include it in the example you posted...

Comment: `__init__` need not be defined unless you want the connection to be established when `DB` is instantiated. Since that is not absolutely necessary, I left it out. Now, you say db.query() generates an exception every time it is called, and I say it does not. Either our setups are different or we are running different code. I've modified your code to make it runnable (you just have to supply your own user/password/host/dbname in config.py). That way we have a common base to start from. I encourage you to run my code to see if you still see an exception with every call to `db.query`.

Comment: I think I found the root of my problem.  My `db` variable is instantiated within my parent process while my method that calls `db.query` is in a forked subprocess.  I believe that, while I am passing db to the subprocess, it is no longer linked to the instance in the main process when attempting to utilize it in a call.  Since your example worked for me also, and my context still doesn't that is the only reasoning I can produce.  Care to chime in?

Comment: Yes, I think you found the source of the problem. When a process forks, all its variables are copied. So each process (the parent and the subprocess) each has its own independent copy of `db`. If after the fork the db connection was established in the parent process, then the db.conn attribute would not be set in the subprocess at the same time. Unlike threads, there is no automatic sharing of variable states between separate processes.